# How to make powershell with itextsharp edit multiple pdfs

Tags: powershell

I managed to make a script that opens a pdf file, reads it, makes 2 variables with information from it and saves the file using those variables, but i cant make it do that to all the pdf files in a folder. i dont know if anyone can help me. This is what i have so far:

```
    $file = "C:\Users\..." #path to my pdf file

    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\...\itextsharp.dll"
    $pdf = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList $file

    $text=[iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($pdf,1)

    $startss = $text.LastIndexOf("Completo")

    $endss = $text.LastIndexOf("Doc")

    $name = $text.Substring($startss +9,$endss - $startss-10)

    $startss2 = $text.LastIndexOf("Modalidad")

    $endss2 = $text.LastIndexOf("(Entre")

    $mode = $text.Substring($startss2 +10,$endss2 - $startss2-10)

    $pdf.Close()

    Rename-Item -NewName ($name + "-" + $mode + "-" + ".pdf") -Path "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `foreach loop`. I would recommend reading about [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1) if you're not sure what it is and some basics on [`foreach loops`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/basics-of-powershell-looping-foreach/).

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\...\itextsharp.dll'

$folder = 'C:\Users\path\to\pdf folder'

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter *.pdf) {
    $pdf = [iTextSharp.Text.Pdf.PdfReader]::new($file.FullName)
    $text = [iTextSharp.Text.Pdf.Parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($pdf, 1)
    $startss = $text.LastIndexOf('Completo')
    $endss = $text.LastIndexOf('Doc')
    $name = $text.Substring($startss + 9, $endss - $startss - 10)
    $startss2 = $text.LastIndexOf('Modalidad')
    $endss2 = $text.LastIndexOf('(Entre')
    $mode = $text.Substring($startss2 + 10, $endss2 - $startss2 - 10)
    $pdf.Close()
    $file | Rename-Item -NewName ($name + '-' + $mode + '-' + '.pdf')
}
```

Comment: I knew that i had to incorporate some kind of loop byt everything that i tried didnt work, i did exactly what you told me and it gives me an error: